# Rectangle color data binding in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want the listpicker to be in fullscreen mode. But that is not my issue. I want the listpicker with data binding, exactly similar to the "theme Color" selection list picker in Settings page in Windows Phone. The listpicker should have a square with a color fill, and the color name . 
I know how to use the binding to have the list of color names, but the `<Rectangle>` tag inside the `<DataTemplate>` is not working.

This is the XAML of the Listpicker

```
       <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lpkColor" Grid.Column="1" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"  Margin="8,12,-8,20" FullModeHeader="Select Color" Header="Color">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{Binding color}" Margin="5,30,20,20"></Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Code behind looks like this:

```
   public class PickerObject
    {


        public string ColorName { get; set; }
        public Color color{get;set;}
        public PickerObject(string cn, Color c)
        {
            ColorName = cn;
            color = c;
        }



    }
```

and inside my MainPage class

`List<PickerObject> MyColors = new List<PickerObject>();`

inside my constructor I have:

```
        MyColors = new List<PickerObject>();
        MyColors.Add(new PickerObject("white",Colors.White));
        MyColors.Add(new PickerObject("black", Colors.Black));
        MyColors.Add(new PickerObject("blue", Colors.Blue));
        MyColors.Add(new PickerObject("yellow", Colors.Yellow));
        MyColors.Add(new PickerObject("red", Colors.Red));
        lpkColor.ItemsSource = MyColors ;
```

But there is no Rectangle shown in the Listpicker, and no color being displayed. 
I would like to know what I am doing wrong, and how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this doesn't work?

```
<ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Margin="0,0,24,0
                       Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Fill="Red"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Red"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

or you have another markup?

**Update**: now a solution

One doesn't simply bind rectangle's `Fill` property to `Color` type.
Because `Fill` property is of type `Brush` as being said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You can extend your markup:

```
<Rectangle Width="50"
           Height="50">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Or you can implement your Color-To-Brush converter. Like this:

In your code-behind include this:

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;

public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Color)
            return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then in your `XAML` you include namespace of this code-behind. Something like:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceForConverterClass"
```

Also include local resources dictionary in your markup with reference to your **Converter** class and named `x:Key` property:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:ColorToBrushConverter x:Key="convertColorToBrush"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Finally you can use converter in your `Rectangle` addressing to it with it's `x:Key` name:

```
<Rectangle Width="50"
           Height="50"
           Fill="{Binding color,
                  Converter={StaticResource convertColorToBrush}}"/>
```

If you're planning to use conversion often, placing **Converter** class in Application Resources Dictionary (**App.xaml** file)  can save your time avoiding repetitive extending markup.

But better if you just use `Brush` directly instead of `Color` I think.

Comment: This actually WON'T work -- you have to use FullModeItemTemplate ;)

Comment: My point was the content of DataTemplate, not rest.
I really don't remember properties of ListPicker but i do believe you. :)

Comment: What I actually wanted was something like this.. I have a list of `MyPicker` objects which I will set as `ItemSource` for the Listpicker. The `MyPicker` has a `Color` property and a `string` property, which I want to use for each item. Each item in the listpicker should have a square with the particular color specified by the object, and the text specified by the string property of the object. What would the xaml look like for this?

Comment: Thank you for the solution.. It works.. The Converter solution didnt work, and raised an exception, but extending the xaml for the SolidColorBrush worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: It raised an exception because i guess you didn't implement your converter. My example was just an example. See edited answer for Converter realization.